# how can i find the info i modified in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I added a printk() in the function `void __init setup_arch(char **cmdline_p)` in /usr/src/linux/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c. And then run make and then `dmesg /var/log` and couldn't see my printk content,how and where can i see them

Answer (score 0):

Take help from kernel log-level

http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Log_Levels

you can use following for enable all logs of kernel

echo 7 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk

hopefully it will help you.

To see kernel logs use -> dmesg it shows you printf of ring buffer of linux().

if there is problem to logs on console then use dmesg > log_file (logs will store in file you can find logs in file)

for more logs of system you can use following

vim /var/log/messages

vim /var/log/syslog

in /var/log/ directory all the system logs exist.

Comment: my printk is KERN_INFO， SO i think the priority is not the problem here but i found that i can't scroll up to first few lines of the messages ,how can i do that

Comment: make sure your modified file is compiling at the time of make.if you will provide more info then i can help you more(after building kernel how you are using, how you are configuring ,how you are building kernel image and other stuff)

Comment: I ran dpkg and got linux-image.xxx.deb and linux-headers.xxx.deb i used make menuconfig but did nothing should be the default setting. I think the problem is where i insert the printk . Maybe i inserted it in a place cant be printed out.I inserted this after #else
0873         printk(KERN_INFO "Command line: %s\n", boot_command_line);